# processing a form after submit in overlay instead of new windows

Tags: jquery, forms, popup, submit

i have an html form whith an action url... till now if i press the submit button the progress continued in a new window. Now i want it to continue i an div overlay or something like this...

My site: http://www.bayers-hotel.de/ if u fill out the dates and then click on "prüfen" u will se...

what i want to have: http://brecherspitze.com/index.php/de/
if u scroll down there is on the left side a box "BUCHUNG" after click on SUCHEN the process woul continued in a overlay...

i found a lot of examples how to open a popup with an content after click on submit. but not how i can continue the booking process in the new popup, cause the information from the form are ...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and send the returning data into your popup.

I can't give an explicit example, your issue is too complex.